# Cplex installition on High Sierra fails

Tags: cplex, macos-high-sierra

I downloaded cplex studio v 12.80 for Mac OS. However, when I double click installation application, application automatically terminated within a few seconds. When I check my system logs, I found following messages:

- cplex_studio1280-osx[50634]: assertion failed: 17C88: libxpc.dylib + 72637 [F7E5F1BC-614B-39CB-B6CE-92A9C7B7EC0B]: 0x89

My os version is High Sierra 10.13.2. I don't know what to do.

Comment: If you try running the installer from the command line do you get any extra output? For example, try running `open /path/to/cplex_studio1280-osx.app` in the terminal. I don't have a Mac to test this on, so it's just a guess. Here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) for the `open` command.

Comment: By the way, it looks like 10.13 is not officially supported for CPLEX 12.8. See the [detailed system requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27019100).

Comment: I had tried running app from terminal. But there was no extra output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your operation language (from system preferences -> language and region) to "English". Probably it will fix it.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=50434089-8ef9-4330-b7f5-6a6c7f9d8467
Thanks anyway.